Error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'offset'
when im trying to execute the code its getting error from offset , in mem filter , need to get pool keys from this
from solana.rpc.types import MemcmpOpts, DataSliceOpts
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
import construct
import asyncio
from solders.rpc.requests import GetProgramAccounts
from borsh_construct import CStruct, U64, Bytes, U128
from construct import Bytes, Int8ul, Int32ul, Int64ul, Pass, Switch
from base58  import b58decode, b58encode
PUBLIC_KEY_LAYOUT = Bytes(32)

# Define constants and initialize Solana client
RPC_URL = "https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key"
connection = AsyncClient(RPC_URL, "confirmed")

# Public keys for base and quote tokens
WSOL_MINT = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"  # WSOL mint address
QUOTE_MINT = "CJduScRXPGpkT3oKuu2mNny5Do9vzL46guxXwAP4pump"
base = Pubkey.from_string(WSOL_MINT)
quote = Pubkey.from_string(QUOTE_MINT)
print(f"sad{base} fdf{quote}")

# Constants for Raydium
AMM_PROGRAM_ID = Pubkey.from_string("AMM5p5yAx2m9T8p7K8v8SYJGtZo2PYJ9yya9CZKyUiSv")  # Raydium AMM V4 Program ID
LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4_SPAN = 752  # Size of the liquidity state layout V4 in bytes


# Function to fetch market accounts
async def fetch_market_accounts(connection: AsyncClient, base: Pubkey, quote: Pubkey, commitment: str) -> dict[str, any]:
    try:
        # Create memory comparison filters using MemcmpOpts
        base_mint_filter = MemcmpOpts(
            offset=LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.baseMint,
            bytes=str(base)
        )
        quote_mint_filter = MemcmpOpts(
            offset=LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.quoteMint,
            bytes=str(quote)
        )

        # Create the config object for fetching program accounts
        data_size_filter = {"dataSize": LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4_SPAN}

        # Fetching program accounts
        accounts = await connection.get_program_accounts(
            pubkey=AMM_PROGRAM_ID,
            filters=[data_size_filter, base_mint_filter, quote_mint_filter],
            encoding="base64",
            commitment=commitment
        )
        
        print(accounts)

        # Decode the data and format it
        raw_data = [{
            "id": str(pubkey),
            "data": LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(account.data)
        } for pubkey, account in zip(accounts.keys(), accounts.values())]

        # Assuming only one relevant account is found, return the first object
        obj = raw_data[0] if raw_data else None
        print(f'fetch_market_accounts', obj)
        return obj
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'fetch_market_accounts', error)

# Running the function
asyncio.run(fetch_market_accounts(connection, base, quote, "confirmed"))


Your data_size_filter is incorrect, and just needs to be a number. Try this:
data_size_filter = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4_SPAN

Based on the get_program_accounts documentation for the filters parameter: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/3f40b01cb6aefb79259ca7ed8cff573ab1f02de0/src/solana/rpc/api.py#L625, you just need to pass an int.
